# Images doesn't move (Phaser 3)

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I've been following a YouTube tutorial on how to use Phaser 3 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVlNZgX5fV8&list=PLDyH9Tk5ZdFzEu_izyqgPFtHJJXkc79no&index=4) and I can't get my images to move.
I copied his code but the only result I got is the static images and a warning/notice on DevTools' console about AudioContext (referring to the Autoplay policy).

[image: It should be on movement]

```js
class Scene2 extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super("playGame");
    }

    create() {
        // 4.1 make the background a tile sprite
        //this.background = this.add.image(0, 0, "background");
        this.background = this.add.tileSprite(0, 0, config.width, config.height, "background");
        this.background.setOrigin(0, 0);

        this.ship1 = this.add.image(config.width / 2 - 50, config.height / 2, "ship");
        this.ship2 = this.add.image(config.width / 2, config.height / 2, "ship2");
        this.ship3 = this.add.image(config.width / 2 + 50, config.height / 2, "ship3");

        this.add.text(20, 20, "Playing game", {
            font: "25px Arial",
            fill: "yellow"
        });

    }

    // 0 add the update function
    update() {

        // 1.1 call a function to move the ships vertically
        this.moveShip(this.ship1, 1);
        this.moveShip(this.ship2, 2);
        this.moveShip(this.ship3, 3);

        // 4.2 scroll the background
        this.background.tilePositionY -= 0.5;

    }

    // 1.2 create the function to move the ships
    moveShip(ship, speed) {
        // increase the position of the ship on the vertical axis
        ship.y += speed;
        // if the ship hits the bottom of the screen call the reset function
        if (ship.y > config.height) {
            // 2.1 call a reset position function
            this.resetShipPos(ship);
        }
    }

    // 2.2 create the reset position function
    resetShipPos(ship) {
        // put the ship on the top
        ship.y = 0;
        // put the ship on a random position on the x axis
        var randomX = Phaser.Math.Between(0, config.width);
        ship.x = randomX;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the 'Audio' Warning, you ignore.*(for details, why you could checkout [this article](https://blog.ourcade.co/posts/2020/phaser-3-web-audio-best-practices-games/))*. But why your code doesn't work is not so clear since, as you can see, in this demo, your code basically works.

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: {
        create,
        update,
        extend:{
          moveShip,
          resetShipPos
        }
    },
    banner: false
}; 

function moveShip(ship, speed){
    ship.y += speed;
    if (ship.y > config.height) {
        this.resetShipPos(ship);
    }
}

function create () {

        this.ship1 = this.add.image(config.width / 2 - 50, config.height / 2, "ship");
        this.ship2 = this.add.image(config.width / 2, config.height / 2, "ship2");
        this.ship3 = this.add.image(config.width / 2 + 50, config.height / 2, "ship3");

        this.add.text(20, 20, "Playing game", {
            font: "25px Arial",
            fill: "yellow"
        });
}

function update(){
    this.moveShip(this.ship1, 1);
    this.moveShip(this.ship2, 2);
    this.moveShip(this.ship3, 3);
}

function resetShipPos(ship) {
    ship.y = 0;
    var randomX = Phaser.Math.Between(0, config.width);
    ship.x = randomX;
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

> **Info:** if you run a phaser application, without a webserver, you will have CORS problems since. read [this article](http://phaser.io/tutorials/getting-started-phaser3) for details, and possible solutions.

Comment: But that's why I don't undestand; If I debug in VS code, it runs without the images (because of CORS policy). I've tried to use wamp server, it loads the images but it doessn't show the animations (the problem i've been having). Also, sorry for the lack of detail, this is my first time using stackoverflow and thanks for your answer :D

Comment: @RickPedroza no Problem, thank you for your Feedback. I uave one question apart from the autoplay warning, is there some other error? not moving animationimages are usually a sign of, some error or may be the webpage is cached in the browser, you could try clearing the browser cache.

Comment: Ok, apparently Stackoverflow hid my answer, but the other error I have is when I debug via VS Code; it shows a CORS policy problem

Comment: @RickPedroza is VScode using the webserver Url in the Browser or the local file? depending on how you setup VSCode to debug, it might cause CORS errors, but this is hard to tell without more information, and I don't know much about VSCode. I would post a new question, with this specific problem and thevscode tag.

Comment: Nope, I'm only running it normally; i'tried to use a webserver, however, the error happened.

Comment: @RickPedroza as mentioned before, if you run a phaser application, without a webserver, you will have CORS problems since. read [this article for details](http://phaser.io/tutorials/getting-started-phaser3).

Comment: I'VE FINALLY RESOLVE IT! As you said, the problem was running without a webserver, só i've tried the Live Server extension and it worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The same thing didn't really work for me.
Opened a project with github.
https://github.com/ansimuz/getting-started-with-phaser/blob/master/part%204%20Game%20Objects%20-%20moving%20Images/Scene2.js
and just copied it.
It helps a lot to clear the browser history if something doesn't work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).